# How to use public private keys in connecting with multiple servers?

Tags: ssh, security, ssh-keys, rsa

Assume I have 4 servers A, B, C and Z and my desktop is MacBox and there is another developer Adam. I have already generated public private key pairs in my MacBox and copied public key to A so that now I can ssh user@A without any problems. Server A now has ~/.ssh/authorized_keys containing public key from MacBox.

(1) Now I want to be able to ssh into B and C from MacBox. Do I need to generate public/private key pairs again for each of B and C? Or I can simply copy public key already generated for A into B and C?

(2) Server Z also wants to be able to connect to B with ssh using keys so that script running on server Z can run remote commands on server B . Do I need to login into Z and generate key pairs and copy public key from server Z to B?

(3) I want Adam to be able to ssh login to server B. Do I need to give password of server B to Adam so that he can generate key pairs and he copies his public key to B? Like all servers B is linux OS and has userB account in addition to root user. I am the owner of server A, B and C. I have the option to create account 'adam' and give adam sudo privileges just like userB so that he can system commands such as starting and stoping services. Still has to figure out if there is any security advantage creating separate account for Adam or just let Adam user userB account.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each user only needs a single ssh public/private key pair.  You append the public key to the user's authorized_keys file on each server you want them to log into.

Most linux distributions provide a tool called ssh-copy-id that does the work for you.  It is similar to the ssh command.  Hopefully Macs have this command too.

So, the answer to your questions are as follows:
1. From MacBox, run "ssh-copy-id user@B" to get your public key into the user's authorized_keys file on server B.  Run "ssh-copy-id user@C" to do the same for server C.

2. You did not specify which user on server Z needs to connect to B.  If userZ already has a ssh key-pair, then you just have to use that.  Again, run the "ssh-copy-id user@B" on server Z to get things set up.
3. Does Adam have an account on server B?  Do you want Adam to use a certain account to log into server B?  If Adam does not have an account on server B, you will probably have to create an account for Adam before doing anything with SSH.  If you want Adam to use a certain account to log into server B, and that account already exists, then no user creation is needed.  Once there is an account for Adam to log into server B with, Adam needs to create a SSH key-pair.  Once Adam has created it, Adam can use the ssh-copy-id program to get the public key portion onto server B.  Running "ssh-copy-id B" is the same as "ssh-copy-id Adam@B" if Adam has his own account.  Running "ssh-copy-id user@B" will put Adam's public key into user's authorized_keys file on server B.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you for answer, i updated the question to clarify.

Comment: Re: OP’s edit: Give Adam his own account.  Essentially Adams keypair can be used in place of his password.  He can use his same keys for all 3 servers or generate different.  Since only Adam has his private key only Adam can use Adams account.   This way if you want to disable Adam’s account, or give it more/less privileges you can.  I create accounts with a password and once the keypair works then disable password.

Comment: Recent versions of macOS do have `ssh-copy-id`, but I'm not sure what version first added it.